# Quickfixj 1.4.0 - socket exception (Host address:port) An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, sockets, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm trying to send fix messages to third party and i'm receiving this message:

```
'Socket Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'.
```

It's strange because my application logs that the message was sent, but the third-party says it doesn't reach them. After a minute it logs this issue. The fromApp method it's never triggered. After that my application requests for logon, and starts to exchange heartbeats succesfully with the exchange. This problem is driving me nuts. As you can see i've sent a message 2:04:44 pm with 34=12, who took too long and i got a heartbeat from the other side with sequence 34=12 as an 'answer'. Anyone knows what could be causing that problem ??

```
Sep 17, 2020 2:04:44 PM quickfix.Session send INFO: FIX.4.4:MySenderCompId->MyTargetCompId: 8=FIX.4.49=217635=n34=1249=MySenderCompId52=20200917-17:04:44.45256=MyTargetCompId11=0000023820200917990000160036227958260=20200917-17:04:43.3899225=message id20001= ...my xml...

Sep 17, 2020 2:04:47 PM quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler messageReceived INFO: FIX.4.4:MySenderCompId->MyTargetCompId: 8=FIX.4.49=6135=034=1249=MyTargetCompId52=20200917-17:04:47.01656=MySenderCompId10=034

Sep 17, 2020 2:04:59 PM quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler messageReceived INFO: FIX.4.4:MySenderCompId->MyTargetCompId: 8=FIX.4.49=7035=134=1349=MyTargetCompId52=20200917-17:04:59.09756=MySenderCompId112=TEST10=066

Sep 17, 2020 2:04:59 PM quickfix.Session send INFO: FIX.4.4:MySenderCompId->MyTargetCompId: 8=FIX.4.49=7035=034=1349=MySenderCompId52=20200917-17:04:59.16756=MyTargetCompId112=TEST10=063

Sep 17, 2020 2:05:03 PM quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler exceptionCaught SEVERE: socket exception (Host address:port) An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

**Edit:** I've discovered that, if i send a basic/small xml my app works fine, if i send a 'normal'/big xml, this error occurs. Could be a bad xml ?

Thank you,

Comment: That means the third party ended the connection.

Comment: Yeah, but why ? I think i'm getting disconnected because my client takes too long to send the message/or to get the response. What could make my application behave in such a mysterious way ?

Comment: Where you are trying to connected is might be down? or out of service.

Comment: I don't think so, because i can send/receive heartbeat/logon/test messages.